# Codeigniter Query: Mysql query convert into codeigniter query format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please help me How to convert this query into codeigniter query format

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2`
    ON table1.permission_key = table2.permission_key AND
       (table2.role_id is null || table2.role_id="1")
WHERE
    table1.section  ='abc' AND
    table1.sub_section = 'xzy';
```

Comment: Have you tried some PHP code yet?  You are asking for a fair amount of code here.

Comment: At least have a go at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try the following

```
$this->db->select('table1.*')
    ->from('table1')
    ->join('table2', 'table1.permission_key=table2.permission_key AND (table2.role_id is null OR table2.role_id="1")', 'left')
    ->where('table1.section', 'abc')
    ->where('table1.sub_section', 'xzy')
    ->result_array();
```

Comment: This is not working.show error: Error Number: 1241

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Sorry my bad had used || instead of OR. Updated my answer. Can you please check now

Comment: In case if your getting error can you please post here. So that I can help you in better way

Comment: Thanks Dear  Channaveer Hakari

Answer (score 0):

you can type your query as plain sql statement and pass it to `codeiginter` function `$this->db->query();`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.permission_key = table2.permission_key AND AND
       (table2.role_id is null || table2.role_id='1')
       WHERE table1.section  ='abc' AND table1.sub_section = 'xzy'";
$this->db->query($query);
$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 $wherearraydata = array('table1.section' => 'abc', 'table1.sub_section' => 'xyz');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.permission_key = table1.permission_key' AND (table2.role_id is null OR table2.role_id="1"));
    $this->db->where($wherearraydata); 
    $querydata = $this->db->get();

return $querydata->result_array();
```